# What is the best practice for applications that reside in /opt to be able to create/edit/delete log/config/etc. files as a non-root user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, package

We installed a custom Debian binary package to `/opt/<package name>/` using `dpkg -i <package name>`.  That directory and everything underneath is owned by root.  When run, the application needs to create log files and configuration files within the `/opt/<package name>/` directory.  However, when I start the service as a non-root user with the following command, `service <package name> start`, the program complains that it has invalid file access (which is true).

My questions is how do other custom/non-custom applications handle this situation where one installs software to `/opt` with `dpkg` and needs to run the application as a non-root user in which the application must create, edit, and delete files and directories?

Comment: The answer is: Unix filesystem permissions operate as they're supposed to.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Is there a best practice that applications use to still write to configuration files and log files?